Decrypt aes 256 cbc in ruby which was encrypted in php
I'm trying to decrypt data in Ruby that was encrypted using PHP with the AES-256-CBC algorithm. The PHP decryption code works perfectly, but when I try to replicate the decryption in Ruby, it always fails. Here is the PHP decryption code that works:
<?php
function im_decrypt($ldata, $secret_key, $secret_iv) 
{   
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $key = hash('sha512', $secret_key);
    $iv = substr(hash('sha512', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
    
    $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($ldata), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);

    return $output;
}

// Sample usage
$ldata = "dTZOR..............";
$secret_key = 'key......';
$secret_iv = 'iv.........';

$decrypted_data = im_decrypt($ldata, $secret_key, $secret_iv);
if ($decrypted_data === false) {
    echo "Decryption failed\n";
} else {
    echo "Decrypted Data: " . $decrypted_data . "\n";
}
?>

No matter what I try, the decryption in Ruby always fails. The error message is always "Decryption failed."
Additional Information
The PHP code uses openssl_decrypt with AES-256-CBC.
The key is derived by hashing the secret key with SHA-512 and taking the first 32 bytes.
The IV is derived by hashing the secret IV with SHA-512 and taking the first 16 bytes.
The encrypted data is base64 encoded.
Questions
What am I doing wrong in the Ruby code?
How can I correctly decrypt the data in Ruby that was encrypted using PHP?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Ruby Code Attempt
And here is my attempt to replicate this in Ruby:
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'
require 'digest'

class DecryptionService
  def initialize(encrypted_data, secret_key, secret_iv)
    @encrypted_data = encrypted_data
    @key = Digest::SHA512.digest(secret_key)[0, 32] # AES-256 key must be 32 bytes
    @iv = Digest::SHA512.digest(secret_iv)[0, 16]   # IV must be 16 bytes
  end

  def decrypt
    decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
    decipher.decrypt
    decipher.key = @key
    decipher.iv = @iv
    decoded_data = Base64.decode64(@encrypted_data)
    decrypted_data = decipher.update(decoded_data) + decipher.final
    decrypted_data
  rescue OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError => e
    puts "Decryption failed: #{e.message}"
    nil
  end
end

# Sample usage
encrypted_data = "dTZOR.............."
secret_key = 'key......'
secret_iv = 'iv.......'

decryption_service = DecryptionService.new(encrypted_data, secret_key, secret_iv)
decrypted_data = decryption_service.decrypt
if decrypted_data
  puts "Decrypted Data: #{decrypted_data}"
else
  puts "Decryption failed"
end


Can you also include some sample data (encrypted + key + iv) in the question so that we can directly run the Ruby version to test?

In the PHP code, the key and IV hashes are hex encoded by default. The ciphertext is Base64 decoded twice (once implicitly by default, once explicitly). This does not seem to be taken into account in the Ruby code. The PHP code contains several vulnerabilities and inefficiencies and should not be used.

@Topaco How would i decode twice in ruby? And the decoding should be hex?

Apply Base64.decode64(Base64.decode64(...)) and Digest::SHA512.hexdigest(...).
